# NSTimer allocation as a property

Tags: iphone, nstimer

If I wanted to create a simple class that has three instance variables and methods like

```
    NSInteger seconds;
    NSInteger minutes;
    NSTimer *timer;


- (void)setMinutes:(NSInteger)m;
- (void)setSeconds:(NSInteger)s;
- (NSInteger)minutes;
- (NSInteger)seconds;
```

What I want is to initialize a NSTimer object and have it countdown with those minutes/seconds.  But I'm not sure how to initialize the timer, and release it if I need to (in the event I had multiple timers going).  I know how to use the method:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                target:self 
                               selector:@selector(doTimer:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

I don't see an example of NSTimer needing "alloc", or if it needs to be released as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` returns an instance of `NSTimer`.  Just use properties and override the setter to invalidate the timer

```
    NSTimer *timer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
- (void)setTimer:(NSTimer *)t;



- (void)setTimer:(NSTimer *)t {
    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [timer release];
        timer = nil;
    }

    timer = [t retain];
}
```

Her you have a pointer to the timer using `self.timer`, and when you set `self.timer =  newTimer`, it retains the new one and invalidates and releases the old one.

Important to note is that your setter expects the input timer to be an autoreleased copy.  If you plan on using the NSTimer `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method you are already using, this will be fine.